# Getting a "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error" while trying to add rows to my database with SQLite C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, logic-error

I'm trying to insert a new row into my database with SQLite3, and for some reason I'm getting a SQL logic error.

```
Database dbObject = new Database();

string query = "INSERT INTO info ('firstName, lastName, email') VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @email";

SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbObject.Connection); //Opens chain of commands

dbObject.OpenConnection();     
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firsName", "blank name");
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", "blank last name");
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "blank@gmail.com");

var result = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
dbObject.CloseConnection();

Console.WriteLine("Rows added: {0}", result);

Console.ReadKey();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your query misses bracket at the end (after `@email`).

Moreover, I am not sure about the single quotes you added between `firstName` and `email`. I think they should be removed.

```
"INSERT INTO info (firstName, lastName, email) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @email)";
```

And as a side note that is not relevant to the error, you also need to dispose SQLiteCommand class as it is not disposed by itself. You can do it with [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-47fVpgDqoDF2xak4bmeXpQ&epi=a1LgFw09t88-47fVpgDqoDF2xak4bmeXpQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xrxkcujmruo9e00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-47fVpgDqoDF2xak4bmeXpQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xrxkcujmruo9e00).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the command on how to improve my code! But the solution you gave me unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: @Idon'treallyknow You need to be more specific than that, please fix your question to have the code you now have so that we know we're looking at the right version of it. Also be specific about what problems you're having, "didn't work" tells us nothing.